# boxing on dynamic data type in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

Type checking for an `Object` takes place at compile time where as type checking for `dynamic` data type takes place at run time then how can we box a dynamic value into Object?

```
dynamic dynamic = "This is dynamic data type";
Object obj = dynamic;
Console.WriteLine(obj);
```

Comment: Consider not to use reserve words for variable name

Comment: @Rahul `dynamic` isn't a reserved word.

Comment: @Servy, but not a good practice as well right?

Comment: @Rahul yes, not good practice to name your variable the data type it is. Even if that wasn't good practice, what's the point in naming a variable the same thing as the datatype?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`dynamic` is *already* always an `object` - it is essentially *implemented* as `object`, with different rules on how invocation happens. So there's nothing to box between `dynamic` and `object`. Additionally, a `string` literal is an `object`, so: there's nothing to box *there*.

No boxing required here. You already have an `object`. The implicit type conversion from `dynamic` to `object` is a no-op.

Comment: I understand both are objects and there is no need to box dynamic data type but what I can't get is how the C# compiler will decide the data type of Object if it's value which is dynamic datatype and it needs to be decided at run time?

Comment: @Nofi there's nothing to decide... there is literally no decision to make. All it is doing is storing the existing reference variable into another reference variable. At the IL level, this is just loading a string (ldstr), storing it into a variable (stloc), loading a variable (ldloc), then storing it into another variable (stloc).